# How to change UserControl content to another UserControl through main view model. How to navigate between content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a main window with a side bar for navigation and a usercontrol in which I am showing 3 views (default, view1, view2). In the main view model (called AppVM), I am initializing the contentcontrol to the default view which has a button to progress to view1 (apart from the navigation sidebar). I have commands in AppVM to shift to any of three views. View1 then has another button which is supposed to move to view2 (using the command present in the main view model). However, whenever I press the button in view1 (to move to view2), the display doesnt change. What is peculiar is that when debugging, when pressing the button in view1, the variable to which the content control is bound to is set to the Default view rather than the current view which is view1.

I think that the way I have set the command up, it creates a new instance of the content control bound variable but I cant figure out how to make it use the same instance and not open new instances again and again.

Main View Model (AppVM)

```
  public class AppVM : ObservableObject
    {

        //Create a property that controls current view
        private object _currentView;
        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            private set
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(ref _currentView, value);
            }
        }

        private string _textboxText;

        public string TextboxText
        {
            get { return _textboxText; }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(ref _textboxText, value);
            }
        }


        //Instantiate the relaycommands, we will need to instantiate relaycommand objects for every command we need to perform. 
        //This means that we will need to do this for preses of all buttons
        public RelayCommand View1ButtonCommand { get; private set; }
        public RelayCommand View2ButtonCommand { get; private set; }

        public RelayCommand DefaultCommand { get; private set; }



        public AppVM()
        {

            //CurrentView = this;
            CurrentView = new DefaultVM();
            View1ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowView1, AlwaysTrueCommand);
            View2ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowView2, AlwaysTrueCommand);
            DefaultCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowDefault, AlwaysTrueCommand);


        }

        public void ShowDefault(object dummy)
        {
          //  CurrentView = null;
            CurrentView = new DefaultVM();

        }

        public void ShowView1(object dummy)
        {
            //CurrentView = null;
            CurrentView =  new View1(dummy as string);

        }

        public void ShowView2(object dummy)
        {
            // CurrentView = null;
            CurrentView =  new View2();
        }


        public bool AlwaysTrueCommand(object dummy)
        {
            return true;
        }       
    }
```

View1 VM

```
public class View1VM : ObservableObject     {

        public InfoClass View1InfoClass { get; set; }



        public View1VM()        {           View1InfoClass = new InfoClass //Apparently I  need to instantiate and initialize this to activate binding          {

                FirstName =  "Abbas",
                //FirstName = passedInforClass,
                LastName = "Syed",
                Number = 12

            };


        }   }
```

Command in view1.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:AppVM x:Name="AppVMinView1" x:Key="AppVMinView1"></vm:AppVM>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:View1VM></vm:View1VM>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="Aqua">
        <StackPanel Margin="100">
            <TextBlock Text="First Name"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="firstNameTextBoxView1" Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.FirstName, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Last Name"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="lastNameTextBoxView1" Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.LastName, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Random Useless Number" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="randomUselessNumberView1" Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.Number, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>

            <TextBlock Text="First Name Entered"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.FirstName}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Last Name Entered" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.LastName}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Random Useless Number Entered"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.Number}"></TextBlock>

            <Button DataContext="{DynamicResource AppVMinView1}" Content="Go to view2" Height="20" Width="70" Command="{Binding View2ButtonCommand}" />



        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

From what I have read (here and on the internet), I need to make the views a singleton, the way I tried doing it was to declare a static property for view2 initialized to a new view2 with a private setter, but that didnt cut it. I would be grateful for any help in this.

I should also add that even when the button in view1 to change to view2 doesnt work, the side navigation bar buttons work just fine.

Comment: Your formatting of the question is very odd. Some code even doesn't show. Code is supposed to be formatted as code only and not as blockquote.

Comment: Your `Button` has the worng `DataContext` set. The `DataContext` must be `AppVM`, otherwise the `Command` binding doesn't resolve. There is no use to make the views singletons.

Comment: Hello BionicCode. Thank you for the reply and also pointing out the incorrect formating (sorry for that ! )

I am binding it to AppVM, but when debugging, upon clicking the Button in View1 to navigate to View2, I reach the breakpoint in AppVM but the CurrentView variable is set to DefaultVM (however it should be View1 [which was the last value for it]).

Comment: It looks like you are creating multiple instances of AppVm. Make sure you are always using the same instance. The instance you are modifying is not the instance that triggers the new view.

Comment: Hello BionicCode. Thank you for getting back to me. Thats the part I am confused on actually. I read that one can declare a static property of the main view model (AppVM) to use the same instance. However, since I have non-static members  (the commands), I cannot have a static constructor. Is there another way to do it? 

I am sorry if I sound stupid, this is my first project.

Thank you for your time with this!

Comment: Don't feel stupid. Lacking knowledge is not stupidity. The former can be fixed by learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are creating multiple instances of `AppVm`.
The button in `View1` and the buttons of the navigation bar obviously don't bind to the same instance of `AppVm`.
Same applies to the `CurrentView` property: your content host binds to a different instance i.e. different property value references, than the `CurrentView` you are modifying in `View1`. Therefore changing `CurrentView` from inside `View1` has no effect on the content host --> view never changes.
Make sure you always reference the same (shared) instance in the same context.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, based on the structure of your UI. Creating a Singleton of the view model class is by far the worst choice. Singletons should and could always be avoided.

The simplest solution would be to declare the view model as a resource in the App,xaml `ResourceDictionary`:

**App.xaml**
Resources defined in this file are globally available in any XAML context via the `StaticResource` markup extension resource dictionary lookup.

```
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <AppVM x:Key="AppVMinView1" />
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Within any XAML file (application scope):

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <View1VM />
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <!-- Reference resources defined in App.xaml, using the StaticResource markup extension -->
  <Button Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppVMinView1}, Path=View2ButtonCommand}" />
</UserControl>
```

---

### Recommended Solution

It also looks like you are creating instances of your views or pages  inside your view model (I assume that `new View1(dummy as string)` creates a control, since the view model is named `View1VM`). Working only with view models instead also solves your problem in a more elegant way.

It is very important to use a single instance of the page view models, in case you don't want to lose state (and data) when switching views. (Don't confuse this with a Singleton, which is a design pattern, that ensures a single instance is used *globally*, by assigning it to a `static` property. Singleton Pattern is commonly considered an anti-pattern.)

This is a short but complete example on how to show and navigate pages:

**AppVM.cs**

```
// Main view model
class AppVM : ObservableObject     
{
  // Create a property that controls current view
  private ObservableObject _currentView;
  public ObservableObject CurrentView
  {
    get => _currentView; 
    private set => OnPropertyChanged(ref _currentView, value);
  }

  private Dictionary<string, ObservableObject> Pages { get; set; }

  public AppVM()
  {
    // Create and store the pages, 
    // so that the same instances can be reused. 
    // All pages must extend ObservableObject (or any other common base type).
    this.Pages = new Dictionary<string, ObservableObject>()
    {
      { nameof(DefaultVM), new DefaultVM() },
      { nameof(View1VM), new View1VM() },
      { nameof(View2VM), new View2VM() },
    };    

    // Initialize first page
    this.CurrentView = this.Pages[nameof(DefaultVM)];

    this.DefaultCommand  = new RelayCommand(param => this.CurrentView = this.Pages[nameof(DefaultVM)], param => true);
    this.View1ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.CurrentView = this.Pages[nameof(View1VM)], param => true);
    this.View2ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.CurrentView = this.Pages[nameof(View2VM)], param => true);
  }  
}
```

**View1.xaml**

```
<!-- DataContext is inherited from the surrounding DataTemplate and is the corresponding page view model -->
<UserControl>    
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding View1InfoClass.FirstName}" />

    <!-- 
      Bind to the command of the same view model instance,
      which is the DataContext of the content host 
    -->
    <Button Content="Show View2"
            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MainWindow}, Path=DataContext.View2ButtonCommand}" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <AppVM />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>

    <!-- Define the views as implicit (keyless) DataTemplate -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DefaultVM}">
      <DefaultView />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type View1VM}">
      <View1 />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type View2VM}">
      <View2 />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <!-- 
    Host of the pages.
    The implicit DataTemplates will apply automatically 
    and show the control that maps to the current CurrentView view model
  -->
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: Hello BionicCode. Thank you so so much for the detailed answer!